# Регулярное выражение. Поиск строк начинающихся с маленькой буквы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть большой текст. Хочу отредактировать с помощью регулярки в notepad++.(в ней полный ноль)
Конечная цель найти строки в которых первый символ не является заглавным и присоединить к предыдущей строке.
Беда в поиске. Уже пытался (скрин).

[image: попытки]

Comment: Вам, кажется, нужно искать `\R([а-яё])` и заменить на `$1` (или пробел + `$1`). Только включите опцию "Учитывать регистр"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

*Найти*:       `\R([а-яё])`
*Заменить*: `$1`

Или, если хотите добавить пробелы:

*Найти*:       `\h*\R([а-яё])`
*Заменить*:  `$1`

**Включите** опцию *Учитывать регистр*.

**Подробности**

- `\h*` - 0+ горизонтальных пробельных символов
- `\R` - любая комбинация символов, задающая 1 перевод на новую строку
- `([а-яё])` - захватывающая подмаска №1 (`$1` в шаблоне замены ссылается на значение этой подмаски): одна строчная русская буква.

До замены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После замены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Текст с кириллицей должен быть в формате UTF-8. В этом случае Notepad ++ сможет искать по такому шаблону:

```
^[\x{0430}-\x{0451}].*
```

Здесь 0430 это codepoint **а**, 0451 - **ё**.

Заметьте, что в [кодовой таблице](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Cyrillic) `ё` идёт через символ после `я`...

---

Возможно, такой вариант тоже сработает:

```
/^[а-ё].*/u
```

Здесь **u** в конце указывает на Unicode выражение